# Reloading an SSLServerSocket after a keystore change without closing and creating a new socket

Tags: java, networking, ssl

I have opened a SSLServerSocket which is created from a SSLContext object which gets loaded with a truststore and keystore. In addition to that, I also have a separate editor program which edits the keystore, i.e. add/remove certificates, etc. In the event that the keystore or truststore changes, is there a way to load it to the SSLServerSocket without closing it and creating a new one.

```
sslContext.init( keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null );
serverSocket = ( SSLServerSocket ) sslContext.getServerSocketFactory().createServerSocket( getPort() );
serverSocket.setNeedClientAuth( true );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reloading a java.net.http.HttpClient's SSLContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69506869/reloading-a-java-net-http-httpclients-sslcontext)

Answer (score 2):

No there isn't, but closing it and quickly opening a new one shouldn't hurt you. Clients that try to connect in the interim will get connection failures, ditto any pending clients in the backlog queue, but you should be able to get it all done in a second or less.